# React.js criando diversos componentes com arrays

Tags: javascript, array, react, componentes, component

Estou tentando criar vários componentes `<Pit />` porém, um a cada resultado vindo da API, sem excluir o já criado anteriormente.

A API retorna um objeto com 2 arrays dentro, a solução foi colocar cada array em uma variável do state e passar como props diretamente para o componente Pit.

Porém, desta forma posso criar apenas 1 componente Pit e cada retorno da API sobrescreve o criado anteriormente...

Meu código está assim:

```
myCallback = (dataFromChild) => {
    this.setState({cod_ativo_search: dataFromChild});
    this.callApi(dataFromChild);
}

async callApi(dataFromChild) {
    const response = await api.get(`/ativo/ativo?cod_ativo='${dataFromChild}'`);

    if(response.data[0].valueOf().rows.length != 0 || response.data[1].valueOf().rows.length != 0){

      this.setState({ responseCompra: response.data[0].rows })
      this.setState({ responseVenda: response.data[1].rows })
      this.setState({ codAtivo: dataFromChild })

   }
}

 render() {
    return (
    <div> 
        <SearchBar callbackFromParent={this.myCallback}/>
        <Pit responseCompra={this.state.responseCompra} responseVenda={this.state.responseVenda} codAtivo={this.state.codAtivo} />
      </div>
    );
 }
```

Alguma ideia de como posso criar um array e inserir cada novo resultado vindo da API para criar diversos componentes Pit?

Comment: Coloque um array de dados de <Pit> no state: `const dado = {compra: response.data[0].rows, venda: response.data[1]....}; { dados } = this.state; dados.push(dado); this.setState(state => ({state, dados: dados}));`. Use um loop para criar os Pit: `{ dados } = this.state; const pits = dados.map(d => <Pit responseCompra={d.compra}... />); return (<div>{pits}</div>);`

Comment: @mari deu certo a parte de criar vários Pits, porém para funcionar tive que fazer assim:

`const dado = {compra: this.state.responseCompra, venda: this.state.responseVenda}; 
this.state.dados.push(dado);

const pits = this.state.dados.map(d => <Pit responseCompra={d.compra} responseVenda={d.venda} />);`

Só que `dados` no state está duplicando e criando cards duplicados, segue imagem de como está ficando o state duplicado

[state_duplicado](https://imgur.com/a/v94XN6n)

O que está errado?

Comment: @mari encontrei uma solução, sua resposta ajudou muito, escreve na resposta pra eu marcar como solução por favor, eu complemento o que fiz no comentário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque um array de dados de  no state:

```
const dado = {compra: response.data[0].rows, venda: response.data[1]....}; 
const { dados } = this.state; 
dados.push(dado); 
this.setState(state => ({state, dados: dados}));.
```

E no render use um loop para criar os Pit:

```
const { dados } = this.state; 
const pits = dados.map(d => <Pit responseCompra={d.compra}... />); 
return (<div>{pits}</div>);
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-5kwi3)

Answer (score 1):

Funcionou, precisei de apenas uns ajustes, no fim ficou assim:

```
const dado = {
      compra: this.state.responseCompra,
      venda: this.state.responseVenda
};

this.state.dados.push(dado);
```

no render

```
const pits = this.state.dados.map((d, i) => {
            return (
                <Pit
                    key={i} 
                    compra={d.compra} 
                    venda={d.venda}  />
            );
        })

return(
   <SearchBar callbackFromParent={this.myCallback}/>
   <div>{pits}</div>
)
```

Comment: [Não se deve alterar o state alterando diretamente os objetos. Você deve sempre usar o setState](https://codeburst.io/the-7-most-common-mistakes-that-react-developers-make-8ff64fc8c61). Também não é necessário setar compra e venda no state para depois adicionar no array dados (vou atualizar minha resposta com um código completo para exemplificar melhor).

Comment: Agora sou eu que pergunto =) O que é esse `callbackFromParent`?

Comment: É uma prop passada para o componente SearchBar, que recebe o valor da pesquisa, faz uma tratativa e devolve assim `this.props.callbackFromParent(this.state.ValorPesquisa.toUpperCase());` para a função `myCallback` do componente que fez a chamada.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta e pelo novo exemplo, vou revisar meu código =)